# Overwriting Class Methods to define Kwargs - Which is Pythonic?

Tags: python, overriding

I'm working on an abstraction layer to a database, and I have a super class defined similar to this:

```
class Test():
    __init__(self, object):
        self.obj = object

    @classmethod
    def find_object(cls, **kwargs):
        # Code to search for object to put in parameter using kwargs.

        return cls(found_object)
```

I then break down that superclass into subclasses that are more specific to the objects they represent.

```
class Test_B(Test):
    # Subclass defining more specific version of Test.
```

Now, each separate subclass of Test has predefined search criteria. For example, Test_B needs an object with a = 10, b = 30, c = "Pie".

Which would be more "Pythonic"? Using the find_object method from the super class:

```
testb = Test_B.find_object(a=10, b=30, c="Pie")
```

or to overwrite the find_object method to expect a, b, and c as parameters:

```
@classmethod
def find_object(cls, a, b, c):
    return super().find_object(a=a, b=b, c=c)

testb = Test_B.find_object(10, 30, "Pie")
```

Comment: Why not write dispatcher function, that pick the correct class up to pass kwargs to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one. "Explicit is better than implicit"  - [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): line 2

Comment: Nope. "Simple is better than complex." - line 3

Answer (score 0):

`Test.find_object` isn't intended to be used directly, so I would name it

```
@classmethod
def _find_object(cls, **kwargs):
    ...
```

then have each child class call it to implement its own `find_object`:

```
@classmethod
def find_object(cls, a, b, c):
    return super()._find_object(a=a, b=b, c=c)
```

When using `super`, it's a good idea to preserve the signature of a method if overriding it, because you can never be certain for which class `super` will return a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

[skilsuper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171672/overwriting-class-methods-to-define-kwargs-which-is-pythonic/30171838#30171838) - you're right about

> Explicit is better than implicit

However, that doesn't mean the first answer is better - you can still apply the same principal on the second solution: `find_object(10, 30, "Pie")` is implicit, but nothing is stopping you from using `find_object(a=10, b=30, c="Pie")` (you *should* use it).

**The first solution is problematic**, because you might forget an argument (for example, `find_object(a=10, b=30)`). In that case, the first solution will let it slide, but the second solution will issue a `TypeError` saying that you're missing an argument.

Comment: Fair point. Both are runtime errors though (presumably find_object will throw `ObjectNotFound` or similar), so I don't see any benefit from the added complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If you accidentally use `find_object(a=10, b=30)` in the second case it won't be a runtime error. I tried it and I get `TypeError: find_object() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: My bad, wrong again :(  - edit: I just tried and it is a runtime error.  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: `ipython -i script.py`

Comment: But if the call never happens the code runs fine, e.g. `if False: find_object(a=1, b=2)`?

Comment: You're right - it will only issue a `TypeError` when you call it, but I think that the first solution won't issue an error at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77533/discussion-between-skolsuper-and-tennabey).